# Unity Input.Touches if hold touch do nothing?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Newbie...
Learning Unity to make mobile games and I have a small hex grid map that when touched the tiles change to a random color. I have a script for the camera to move it around with a finger press and zoom in an out with two fingers.

I want the tiles to only change color on a single touch, and not change when I pan or zoom the camera. I have been trying for two days and googled myself out and can't seem to figure it out. It seems pretty simple.

Here is the code that is called from Update() when a raycast hits an object. This just changes the hex's color but I want it to only do it when not panning or zooming the camera.

```
void Touch_Hex(GameObject ourHitObject)
{
    Touch[] touches = Input.touches;

    if (touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        MeshRenderer mr = ourHitObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>();

        mr.material.color = color[Random.Range(0, color.Length)];
    }
}
```

I've tried all different combos of phases etc but just cannot get it to work as I want it. I'm thinking deltaTime or deltaPostion is the answer but I can't work it out.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a combination of a `boolean` variable and `touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Moved`. When `touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Moved` is `true` then your input is now considered to be invalid. You can then set to `boolean` variable to `true` or `false` then use it later on to decide whether to change the color or not.

```
bool onlyTouched;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            //Touched
            onlyTouched = true;
        }


        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            //Moved Finger (Now Invalid!)
            onlyTouched = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            //Check if only touched then change color
            if (onlyTouched)
            {
                Debug.Log("Only touched Finger");
                //MeshRenderer mr = ourHitObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
                //mr.material.color = color[Random.Range(0, color.Length)];

                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                {
                    if (hit.transform != null)
                    {
                        MeshRenderer mr = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
                        mr.material.color = color[Random.Range(0, color.Length)];


                        //hit.transform.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Finger was moved while touching");
            }

            //Reset onlyTouched for next read
            onlyTouched = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, that did exactly as I wanted. Thank you!

Only thing now is that it is super sensitive. Is there a way to set the bool to true/false with a time limit and not the phase.moved? So for instance a hold of say.2 seconds sets the bool to false?

Comment: @Fogazi Nice. Have been waiting to hear if it worked. As for waiting for 2 seconds, that would require the re-write of the all the code. You didn't mention that in the original question. You can create a new question and I will try to answer it.